Excel Connection to Oracle Database using CAC authentication
I have an Excel VBA script that connects to our Oracle database.  It's been working perfectly when I provide a user name and password.  However, our agency has started using CAC authentication.  We are now using a generic user name and no password.  Using this new approach, my code does not work anymore.  Here is what it looks like today.
With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
    "OLEDB;Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle;Password=" & PW & ";User ID=" & ID & ";Data Source=" & DB, _
         Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable

Where PW, ID and DB are variables I read elsewhere in my script.
Does anyone know how to modify my code to use CAC authentication?
Thank you.
Dennis

CAC authentication requires that you get credentials from the certificate on the smart card. Typically you must use the Oracle Client software and the Microsoft Certificate Store as the wallet location. Details are in a white paper I wrote 5 years ago, here: https://pmdba.wordpress.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/configuring_ssl_for_oracle_client_with_cac_using_mcs_4.pdf. Use of CAC authentication implies use of individual accounts to authenticate, not a common account, though the individual accounts could proxy connect to a common account.
